# number of layers in convolution neural network

Tags: image, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner in convolution networks. I use digits to implement them and facing with few doubts.

1. While trying out a basic classification problem of images, how do we decide on the number of layers - how many conv layers/ fully connected layer, etc.
2. In digits we have 3 standard papers implemented, for a particular dataset is there any way to find out which architecture to use – or when should we use our own architecture.
3. How can the hidden layers be helpful in solving the problems – i.e. what possible decisions can we take by looking at the results in the hidden layer

Comment: https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/icdar/2003/1960/02/196020958.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Deciding on how many layers or neurons is needed or the best architecture for building neural network was never clear or possible. the main procedure was taken before is to try building on some parameters and then measure the performance on training set and testing set not bias or to over fit the data and decide on the best parameters, or try some other algorithm like genetic algorithm.

conclusion either you start from scratch every time to measure the network performance or apply other algorithms which doesn't need to start from scratch and can build incrementally by applying transfer learning and fine tuning on the network architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The core philosophy that makes deep learning so democratic and amazing is simple "Don't be a Hero".

What it means is that in most cases the best deep learning models take millions of data points and weeks to train, something most of us cannot achieve with our low performance PC's (yes a single GPU system is low performance). So why would you want to waste your time in building and training NN architectures. Simple you don't.

**Transfer learning is your solution!!** try to find models that are trained on data similar to your problem and use their pre-trained weights to fine tune your data set. Doing this not only do you get an already proven NN architecture but also a major head start in training.

The best place to find pre-trained models is the caffe model zoo so go have a look at it.